Find the domain of a non-elementary function?
This is a question from a exercise in single-variable calculus. I don't understand the question, nor have any clue on how to get to the answer. I am more uncertain about problem a, than problem b.
Help is requested and appreciated.
The question is as follows:

Let $$ g(x) = \int_x^7 \frac{e^t}{t-1} dt$$ where $\int_x^7$ denotes the Riemann integral.

a) What is the domain of the function ( g )?
b) Investigate in which intervals ( g ) is increasing/decreasing by calculating $g'$
This is my attempt to an answer:

$ g(x) = \int_{x}^{7} \frac{e^t}{t-1} \, dt $
(a)
$$
\text{This gives that: } t \neq 1 \text{ and } t \leq 7 \Rightarrow D_f = \{x \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq 1, x \leq 7\}
$$
(b)
The rules for an integral, continuous on the interval [a,b], gives:
$$
g(x) = \int_{x}^{7} \frac{e^t}{t-1} \, dt = - \int_{7}^{x} \frac{e^t}{t-1} \, dt
$$
The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if a function ( f ) is continuous on the interval ([a,b]), then:
$$
S(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt, \quad a \leq x \leq b
$$
The function is differentiable, and the derivative is:
$$
S'(x) = f(x), \quad a < x < b
$$
This gives:
$$
g'(x) = - \frac{e^x}{x-1}, \quad a < x < b
$$
Increasing/Decreasing

$ e^x > 0$ $\forall x\in\mathbb R$.
When $x > 1$, we get: $ g'(x) = \frac{e^x}{x-1} < 0$.
When $x < 1$ , we get: $ g'(x) = - \frac{e^x}{x-1} > 0$

Conclusion: g(x) is increasing on the interval $ (- \infty, 1) $ and decreasing on the interval $ (1, 7)$.

For (a) the integrand must make sense on the entire interval $[x,7]$. So that interval can't contain $1$. So the domain is $(1, \infty)$.
For (b) use what the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells you on that interval.

But why can't $x<1$? That is what I am having trouble understanding. Thanks for responding, by the way. This is what the function looks like: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hemvi5xfxv

In order for the integral to make sense, the function should be defined on the interval $[x,7]$. The process of integration makes use of all function values within the interval. If any of these is undefined, the integral might not make sense.

Okay, I think I understand. Let me repeat what I have understood, and please do correct me if I am wrong. Since the function is not defined at x=1, the integral will need to be divided up in two different integral. Therefore the function which is the integrals value in the interval is maximally defined in $(1,\infty)$ in the first quadrant.

@aconfusedtortoise Almost right. But there is just one interval, $(1, \infty)$. If $x < 1$  then $1$ is between $x$ and $7$ so the integral makes no sense.
